# My Router's Ping Suddenly Gets High from 2 or 3 ms to 40 and 60 ms

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping, wifi-configuration

So I bought a new router after the old one was hit by a lightning; the new one is TP-Link WR840N but what I'm facing is that suddenly the ping gets so high with download/upload speed getting so slow even a WhatsApp message won't go.
I figured out that when I remove the internet cable from the router and re-plug it in everything works fine again.
ps.: This router was the second one I get after the lightning strike since I thought that the first one was malfunctioning so I replaced it from the store with this one, but apparently the problem is not from it.
I tried to contact the internet provider and he did the tests which gave that the ping was about 2 ms that's provided to me so the problem is from my side.
Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: Does your router's status page show the CPU usage anywhere? Does it have firewall logs? The description makes it sound like maybe it's receiving a lot of connection attempts from the internet, or maybe it's just unable to handle your heavy internet usage at that moment.

Comment: Download and run a version of MTR (eg WinMTR) and post the results. This could allow us to infer if the issue is in your WiFI or beyond.

Comment: Have you tried to flush dns?(Open CMD > ipconfig/ flushdns) There is a vedio about how to fix high ping. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Os7B4darDlU

Comment: Using WiFi or wired?